# how to check if a jQuery tab element is not selected

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to add a class to a jQuery tab element only if it is not currently active.

This is my attempt:

```
if (($("#tab2").css("ui-state-active")) == false){
 $( "#tab2" ).addClass( "blink_me" );
}
```

Comment: I think you want `if (!$("#tab2").hasClass("ui-state-active")...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try  `not`

```
 $('#tab2:not(".ui-state-active")').addClass("blink_me")
```

Comment: I would have though `$('#tab2:not(".ui-state-active")').addClass("blink_me")`

Comment: @mplungjan yes, that condition is redundant and one short and sweet line.

Answer (score 2):

You likely meant

```
if ($("#tab2").not(".ui-state-active")... // or !$tab.hasClass("ui-state-active")
```

Or like this:

```
var $tab2 = $("#tab2");
$tab2.toggleClass("blink_me",$tab2.not(".ui-state-active"));
```

Or once:

```
$('#tab2:not(".ui-state-active")').addClass("blink_me")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check the active status by class, `hasClass()` is what you are looking for:

```
if ($("#tab2").hasClass("ui-state-active")
{
    //Active mode
}
else
{
    // Inactive mode
}
```